# Intersection of two curves can define linearly equivalent divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$, $D$ be smooth projective curves of genus $g$ and $g'$ over complex numbers on a smooth projective surface.

Let $C\cap D$ have 2m points. Over each of these curves can m of these points be linearly equivalent to the other m?

Or at least can we extend each set of $m$ points to divisors $E$, $E'$ which are linearly equivalent.

$C$ and $D$ are some arbitrary curves of arbitrary genus. So I am not looking at situations like where all points on curve are linearly equivalent.

Comment: The first part is too strong and the answer is no. The second part is very weak and the answer is yes, in the sense, that if $D, D'$ are two sets of $m$ points, then you can find $E, E'$ on $C$ such that $D+E\sim D'+E'$ on $C$. Similarly, $F,F'$ on $D$ etc.

Comment: @Mohan, I am trying to work out a proof of the second part. Extending points to linearly equivalent divisors. I would like to extend points to divisors of a given degree $d$. Is that possible. Can you give some way to figure.